# How to disable rectangular boxes in Sublime Text?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, editor, sublime-anaconda

[image: Sublime Text Rectangular highlight]

I am unable to get rid of these rectangular boxes, I guess they started appearing after I set Anaconda as my build Package.

Comment: Did you check the settings for the Anaconda package? There should be a setting to turn off code linting.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a ton, it was under *anaconda_linting*, had to change the value to false.